# Is it possible to dynamically create a table from as SSIS source

Tags: sql-server, ssis, odata, etl, oledbdestination

**Objective**: automate creating a table along with all its columns and data types given a SSIS source

My guess is:

1) Pointing Sources to a Destination to a SQL command

[image]

2) Using Select * into ... Problem is I don't know what the *from* equivalent of a source is

[image]

Alternative) Store results in Recordset and pass on to Execute SQL task. Problem then is how to access that result from execute sql task
[image]

Comment: It's not possible to do that. Does the oData schema regularly change, or do you just want to avoid having to manually create the target table

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid  I want to avoid having to manually create the target table

Comment: What I would do: get the field list from somewhere, paste into excel and make a table creation script. You might also be able to use the import/export wizard to create your table.

Comment: After several experimentation and research, I'm leaning towards the conclusion that there is no getting around manually creating each column whether it is done through a [sql task](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/272ddd31-1812-422c-aad7-8671a4c7e0b2/what-is-the-equivalent-of-select-into-in-ssis) or a [script task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex21zs8x(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use a `Recordset Destination` to store data into an `System.Object` Variable, Then use a `Script Task` *(starts after that Data Flow Task is executed)* in which you will select the `System.Object` Variable as `ReadOnly Variable`. and you will write your own code to insert the `Recordset` to SQL using `System.Data.SqlClient.SQLCommand` Object

You can refer to one of these links

- [Issues with SSIS Script Task and SQL Bulk Insert - C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34961468/issues-with-ssis-script-task-and-sql-bulk-insert-c-sharp)
- [Insert DataTable into SQL Table in C#](http://www.morgantechspace.com/2014/04/Insert-DataTable-into-SQL-Table-in-C-Sharp.html)

Comment: Thanks again @hadi. I stored the results in a recordset. Is it possible to pass that result directly to an Execute SQL task? see updated screenshot

Comment: You have to use script task to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

If you need just the structure of table use this trick

```
select top 0 * into NewTable from YourTable
```